# kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813

Tags: nsurlsession

I receive in Xcode the following

```
[804:670059] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

What does it mean? I was trying to find the 9813 but the most common was 9812.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: A Google search for "9813 site:developer.apple.com -site:forums.developer.apple.com" works wonders.  It won't give you a complete explanation, but it will at least give you the error code's name and a brief explanation....  :-)

The error code means:

```
errSSLNoRootCert—The peer’s certificate chain was not verifiable to a root certificate.
```

That means, IIRC, that you're missing intermediate certificates, i.e. that the end of the certificate chain provided by the server is not a self-signed certificate, and is not signed by any of the known root certificates.

Even if I'm remembering wrong, it's definitely a problem with the certificate chain that the server is sending.

This doc should help you debug it further:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2232/_index.html